# Remove Google Chrome Icon From Dash Search

Tags: icons, unity-dash

I just installed Chromium today and removed Google Chrome via `sudo apt-get purge Google-Chrome-stable`

The application is gone, but the shortcut in my menu is still there. Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove it?

Here's a screenshot of what I see when I type in "Chr(om)", which is how I typically search for Chromium.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's check for the remaining launcher:

```
ls /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

if present, remove it with

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
```

You may also need to check the *applications* folder in the user's home directory: `~/.local/share/applications/` and remove `google-chrome.desktop`. (thanks Tchalvak)

Comment: That did it! I forgot all about that folder :P. Thank you!!

Comment: similarly, I had to go to: ~/.local/share/applications/ and rm Google\ Chrome.desktop